# Can you get a bound GAS script from the File?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form (copied from template) that has a bound script. I want to set a form submit trigger on that script, but I cannot figure out if I can get the script when all I have is the file/form.

Maybe it's not possible, or maybe there's an easy answer. I just spent the last hour trying to find something in the documentation or here on the forum.

I guess the next question will be whether I can give the script permission to run programmatically - I think the answer is no, but If you know, give me a quick tip so I can start barking up another tree.

If you know, could you help me? thank you!

Comment: I see that I can programmatically change the destination of the form responses, so I'll take that route and trigger from there. But still curious if anyone knows the answer, seems like a handy thing to be able to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure if this is what you wanted.

You can make sure if the script is present by opening the script editor from Tools> Script editor on the form builder page.

From there you can set up the trigger as in the screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl5Zy.jpg

Let me know if this wasn't what you were looking for and if possible, share the form with the "Add collaborators" button to better see this.

EDIT:

This should help. [Form triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forForm(Form)) To attach it to the form. You'll still need to be in a script editor and run the function that performs this

`ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction') .forForm('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') .onFormSubmit() .create()`

Comment: Hi Karan, thank you for offering a solution. To clarify, what I'm trying to do is what you describe, but through a script, without having to actually open the form myself, and add the trigger.

Comment: This should help.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forForm(Form)

But instrad of "FormApp.getActiveForm()", you can use "FoamApp.openById(id)" to attach it to the form.

You'll still need to be in a script editor and run the function that performs this.

Comment: Done. Glad to be of help.